# Injector error when using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this html

```
<div data-ng-app="myApp">
   <div ng-controller="OAuthCtrl">
       <label >
           <button class="button button-block button-positive" 

           ng-click="facebookLogin()">
               Login with Facebook
           </button>
       </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

and this javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/framework7.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCordova']);

app.controller("OAuthCtrl", function($scope, $cordovaOauth){
    $scope.facebookLogin = function() {

        //user your fb app Id.. 
        $cordovaOauth.facebook(fb_appId, 
        ["email"]).then(function(result) {
            alert(result.access_token);
            // results
        }, function(error) {
            alert("error");
            alert(error);
            // error
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

When i run the code on chrome i get this error

Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector/unpr?p0=%24cordovaOauthProvider%20%3C-%20%24cordovaOauth%20%3C-%20OAuthCtrl

which leads to this link

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$cordovaOauthProvider%20%3C-%20$cordovaOauth%20%3C-%20OAuthCtrl

I am following thsi tutorial to be able to login a uer using his or her own facebook account https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1031475/How-to-Integrate-Facebook-Login-into-a-Cordova-App
Where am i going wrong?.

Comment: The framework is unable to resolve $cordovaOauth in your code. Can you first make sure that all your scripts are loaded correctly and there are no errors?Please look at the console. Are there any errors?

Comment: The error showed above is the only error.

Answer (score 1):

Tutorial you posted is missing some steps. You need to install cordocaOauth and inject it first.

Here are the docs:[ngCordovaOauth on github](https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth/blob/master/README.md)